# back button after starting an Activity in Option Menu

Tags: android

I have 2 activities : MainActivity and DetailActivity.

Initially the App is launched to MainActivity .

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ArrayList<Movie> stringArrayList ;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MovieData mAdapter;
private String name = "popular";
private String string ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.v("LOG_V","onStart() is called");
    string = name ;
    updateMovie(string);
}


public void updateMovie(String s)
{
    new MovieAsyncTask().execute(s);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list,menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id)
    {
        case R.id.top_rated :
            name = "top_rated";
            string = name;
            updateMovie(name);
            break;
        case R.id.popular_movie :
            name = "popular";
            string = name;
            updateMovie(name);
            break;
        case R.id.about :
            Toast.makeText(this,"About",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.upComing_movie :
            name = "upcoming";
            string = name;
            updateMovie(name);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class MovieAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,ArrayList<Movie>>
{
    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Movie> doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream ;
        String jsonString ;

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;


        final String MOVIE_BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/"+params[0]+"?";

        final String APPID_PARAM = "api_key";

        try {

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(MOVIE_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(APPID_PARAM,BuildConfig.OPEN_MOVIE_API_KEY).build();


            URL url = new URL(uri.toString());
            Log.v("URL : ",uri.toString());

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpURLConnection.connect();

            inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line ;
            while ((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                stringBuffer.append(line+"\n");
            }
            if(stringBuffer.length()==0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            jsonString = stringBuffer.toString();

        }catch (IOException I)
        {
            Log.e("LOG_TAG","Error");
            return null;
        }finally {
            if(httpURLConnection!=null)
            {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if(bufferedReader!=null)
            {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }catch (IOException i)
                {
                    i.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
        try {
            return getMovieDataFromJson(jsonString);
        }catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ArrayList<Movie> getMovieDataFromJson(String json) throws JSONException
    {
        ArrayList<Movie> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        final String RESULTS = "results";
        final String POSTER_BASE_URL = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185";
        final String POSTER_PATH = "poster_path";
        final String VOTE_AVERAGE = "vote_average";
        final String BACKDROP_URL = "backdrop_path";
        final String RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(RESULTS);
        Log.v("jsonArray Size :",jsonArray.length()+"");
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String posterUrl = POSTER_BASE_URL+jsonObject1.getString(POSTER_PATH);
            String vote = jsonObject1.getString(VOTE_AVERAGE);
            String date = jsonObject1.getString(RELEASE_DATE);
            String backImageUrl = jsonObject1.getString(BACKDROP_URL);
            Log.v("Poster Url" , posterUrl);
            arrayList.add(new Movie(vote,date,posterUrl,backImageUrl));
        }

        return arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Movie> arrayList) {
        stringArrayList = arrayList ;
        if(arrayList!=null)
        {
            mAdapter = new MovieData(getApplicationContext(),stringArrayList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2));
        }
        super.onPostExecute(arrayList);
    }
}
```

}

```
Recycler View Adapter
```

public class MovieData extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

```
public ArrayList<Movie> movieArrayList ;
public Context mContext ;

public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{

    ImageView imageView ;
    TextView ratingView,releaseView ;
    public viewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        ratingView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating_view);
        releaseView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.release_date);

    }

}

public MovieData(Context context , ArrayList<Movie> arrayList) {
    movieArrayList = arrayList;
    mContext = context ;
}

@Override
public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.content_main,parent,false);

    return new viewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(viewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Movie movie = movieArrayList.get(position);
    final String u = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"+movie.getBackdropUrl();
    Log.v("LOG_TAG",u);
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(movie.getPosterUrl()).into(holder.imageView);
    holder.releaseView.setText("Release : "+movie.getmReleaseDate());
    holder.ratingView.setText("Rating : "+movie.getmRating()+"/10");
    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),DetailActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,u);
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return movieArrayList.size();
}
```

}

```
Detail Activity
```

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
String url ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.detail_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    url = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.backdrop_image);
    Picasso.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.float_button);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

how can i comeback from Detail Activity to the movie list that are selected in menu.

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. Are you trying to go from DetailActivity to MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get back to your `MainActivity` by pressing the back button, then you have to implement the `onBackPressed()` method. More details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()).

Else you can just call the `this.finish()` anywhere in the `DetailActivity` class where you want to exit from the *current* activity and get back to the *parent* activity in the stack.